# ESXi refuses AD join, "The host does not have a suitable FQDN"

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi, ipv6

I have an ESXi 6 hypervisor (**esx.ad.example.com**) that I want to join into an AD domain (**ad.example.com**) with one DC. Both domain controller (**dc.ad.example.com**) and hypervisor have an IPv6 address and working DNS. The domain is resolvable globally and thus no custom DNS server is set. This setup works fine for Windows workstations or guests on the same ESXi joining the same domain.

The real domain name does not end with **example.com**, but is substituted for privacy reasons. Dig output with the same substitution follows, this output is consistent over multiple locations in the world:

```
$ dig NS ad.example.com. +short
dc.ad.example.com.
$ dig AAAA ad.example.com. +short
2001:db8::ad:dc:1
$ dig AAAA dc.ad.example.com. +short @dc.ad.example.com
2001:db8::ad:dc:1
$ dig PTR 1.0.0.0.c.d.0.0.d.a.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. +short
dc.ad.example.com.
```

**To make things clear: The domain ad.example.com uses AD-integrated DNS, but the Windows DNS server on the DC is non-resolving.** A normal resolver, without any forwarders explicitly configured, will still forward all requests for `*.ad.example.com` to `2001:db8::ad:dc:1`, because NS records are in place, as illustrated by the `dig` commands mentioned. If I would add `@8.8.8.8` to the commands, the output would be the same. [According to this Technet article, this means that the domain uses AD-integrated DNS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737383%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

In ESXi, under **Configuration** -> **DNS and Routing**, I have set **Name** to `esx` and **Domain** to `ad.example.com`. Then under **Authentication Services** I set **Directory Services Type** to `Active Directory`. I enter the domain `ad.example.com`, click **Join** and enter credentials. Within a second, the following message appears:

> The host does not have a suitable FQDN.

The only non-standard thing in my setup is that there is no IPv4 connectivity (and non-trivial to set up), otherwise i'd say everything is done by the book. There is no packet filter between the hosts, apart from the default firewall ESXi has, which I have not changed from its defaults. Can it be that the ESXi AD implementation requires IPv4, or is something else wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no custom DNS server is set?" You'll have to tell all domain clients to use local ad integrated DNS for the domain to work.

Comment: `...there is no IPv4 connectivity...`. Do the DCs support IPv6? Have you used the DCs as your DNS servers for the hosts?

Comment: Make sure you have reverse DNS entries, too.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: No custom DNS: The resolver is external, but NS for the domain points to the DC. Domain is *not* under `.local`. DC itself is configured as non-resolving and answers queries from the internet. Windows guests on ESXi don't have a problem with this and join just fine.

Comment: @GregL: The DC supports IPv6 (there is only one). Since the network has no IPv4 connectivity, it wouldn't have any connectivity at all if it didn't have IPv6. The DC is not used as the DNS server, but NS is set up correctly. This is proven by the fact that Windows guests on ESXi can join just fine.

Comment: Windows guests inside ESXi connecting properly has *nothing* to do with ESXi's ability to connect. Check your Name, Domain and DNS settings on ESXi and perhaps even include them in the question for clarity.

Comment: Why is an external DNS server resolving internal names?

Comment: A Windows 2000 or later domain **requires** AD-integrated DNS hosting. AD-integrated DNS servers do have to be Windows servers but they don't have to be DCs. I don't understand the sentence, "The *resolver* is external, but NS for the domain points to the DC." What do the ESXi hosts have listed as their DNS servers? What do you mean by "resolver", just a DNS server? Is it AD-integrated?

Comment: @ewwhite: The "external" DNS server is an on-premise BIND server without custom zones, pure recursive caching resolver. I didn't mean 8.8.8.8 when I said external, only that it wasn't an AD server. Poor choice of words on my part. Do you think it makes a difference if I explicitly add a forwarder to the DC? Or will AD on ESXi only work if it is configured with the DC as DNS server?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: What I meant is that the configured DNS server is a pure on-premise resolver, but not AD-integrated, and that the DC is an authoritative name server, but not a resolver. NS records are in place so that DNS queries to `ad.example.com` are answered by the DC.

Comment: I think I understand. The ESXi servers are pointing to the BIND server for DNS resolution, which is then configured to forward request for the AD domain name to the AD-integrated DNS server hosted on a DC, right? Have you tried changing the ESXi servers to send all DNS queries straight to the AD-integrated DNS service on the DC?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: The question has already been answered, but for completeness: There is no explicit forward to the AD-integrated DNS zone in the BIND server, but an NS record exists in the global DNS system, which points to the AD server. I haven't tried sending all DNS queries straight to the DC, but it doesn't matter which resolver I use, as long as the DC is authoritative for the AD-integrated DNS zone (which it is, due to the NS record). This is illustrated using `dig` commands in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the relevant documentation for your product.

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc%2FGUID-6BC115DF-4EC5-409E-8B74-45525E966F0F.html

The documentation clearly states that ipv6 is not supported for ESXi -> Active Directory communication. (as of 6.0.)

[image: No ipv6]

Comment: While your answer is correct, this response would have been better if you were a little less condescending about it. While it's true you should read documentation about the products you use there are always reasons why you may have missed it, can't find it, or may get to a solution faster by asking others who might already know the answer before wasting hours trying to find the solution. Simply put, that's why this site exists.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if this is a standalone host, it's not worth joining it to a domain. Ideally you join your *vCenter Server* to Active Directory, not the individual hosts.

Answer (score -1):

Prior to trying to join the host to the domain, under the hosts configuration tab, select 'DNS and Routing' and ensure the host informaiton including Name and Domain is populated.